# "Mapping" a Windows application's menus and dialogs?

Tags: windows, capture

I am looking for a program that traverses all menu items and dialogs of a given application in order to capture screenshots and ideally also list all element/widget information  (windows, tabs, groups, labels, input types, mouse hints, ..) as a tree.

I understand it may not be possible to get a perfect representation of the structure, but any automation really would be helpful.

The closest I have found is an AutoHotkey script at http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/7771-extracting-menus/ which I have not tested yet as I assume there are other options for this (documentation) task.

Here is a related Windows API function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751400/get-the-text-within-a-dialog-box

---

Edit: The program sources and MS Visual Studio are available, so another solution would not need to work with the running application but generate the information from the source/VS.

---

Edit 2: Here's a bit of VBA using the API function: http://www.unagibay.com/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=2&tabid=100&itemid=1824